# Bootstrap Navbar won't be fixed on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a website with Bootstrap and i'm finding problems with the navbar. Even though i use the class 'fixed-top', it just won't stay on top as soon as i scroll down.

I think this is a problem with the relative positions of the slides that are creating the page, but i don't know how to fix it and i'm not finding anything online.

```css
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);
    
    .nav-titolo {
     float: left;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .navbar-brand {float:none;}
    
    #titolo {
     height: 200px;
     font-size: 400%;
     font-family: Bree Serif;
    }
    
    html {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    body { 
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
     perspective: 1px;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      font-family: Bree Serif;
    }
    
    h1 {
       font-size: 250%
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 140%;
      line-height: 150%;
      color: #333;
    }
    
    .slide {
      position: relative;
      padding: 25vh 10%;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
     transform-style: inherit;
    }
    
    .back {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 35%;
      width: 320px;
      height: 240px;
      transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    }
    /*
    img:last-of-type {
      transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-104%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);
    }
    */
    .slide:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    }
    
    .title {
      width: 50%;
      padding: 5%;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    }
    
    .slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    .slide, .slide:before {
      background: 50% 50% / cover;  
    }
    
    .header {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 175%;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
    }
    
    #title {
      background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/");
      z-index:2;
    }
    
    #title h1 {
     transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75);
     transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    
    }
    
    #slide1:before {
      background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/");
      transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    }
    
    #slide2 {
      background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/3/");
      z-index:2;
    }
    
    #slide3:before {
      background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/5/");
      transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    }
    
    #slide4 {
      background: #222;
    }
    
    .navbar{
     background:#F97300;
    }
    .nav-link , .navbar-brand{
     color: #f4f4f4;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nav-link{
     margin-right: 1em !important;
    }
    .nav-link:hover{
     background: #f4f4f4;
     color: #f97300;
    }
    .navbar-collapse{
     justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .navbar-toggler{
      background:#fff !important;
    }
    
    .overlay{
     position: absolute;
     min-height: 100%;
     min-width: 100%;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     background: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.79);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>index.html</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
       <div class = "nav-titolo"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Colorizer</a></div>
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#slide1">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#slide2">Section 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#slide3">Section 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#slide4">Section 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div id="title" class="slide header">
      <h1 id = "titolo"> Colorizer </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="slide1" class="slide">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="slide2" class="slide">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
      </div>
      <img class="back" src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
      <img class="back" src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/"> 
    </div>
    
    <div id="slide3" class="slide">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="slide4" class="slide header">
        <h1>The End</h1>
    </div>
    
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about :
CSS:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for aswering. Tried it and it isn't working anyway.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 use 'fixed-top': https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement

Comment: Sure. I supposed by the tag

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, you can add the following code:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
}
```

to your navbar class. That will ensure that the navbar will stay at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Near line 4202 of bootstrap.css it the class should be called .navbar-fixed-top.

```
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1030;
 }
```